# select percent return given two time periods but to different column value

Tags: mysql

I have a query to select the percent of users who return each month,

```
 SELECT
(
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT t1.user )
    FROM mytable t1
    WHERE t1.month = 'November'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM mytable t2
        WHERE t2.user = t1.user
        AND t2.month = 'October'
    )
)
/
(
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT mytable.user )
    FROM mytable
    WHERE mytable.month = 'October'
) * 100
```

But now I would like to see what users return each month but go to a different event instead, so 
the percent who attend one event one month and a different event a different month but NOT taking the original event.

pseudo code would need to be something like this.

```
SELECT  user IN event1 october AND users IN event2 november and users NOT IN event1 november /users IN colorado event1 * 100







   user month event 
   -----------------    
   jack october event2 
   jack november event3 
   jack november event3 
   jack november event2 
   jack december event3
   sam november event2 
   sam november event1
   sam october event1
   sam october event2   
   john october event1
   john november event2
```

Comment: Do you want to select the users who attended events in the month of october and novemeber but went to different event?

Comment: I think I have a grasp on the query and can make it return the user John in my testing, but I don't understand where you get 10% from.  There were only 2 users attending event1 in october, and one of them defected, hence 50%.

Comment: you are right I deleted that

Comment: Ok, I think I understand - answer pending...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By performing an `INNER JOIN` to get a user's activity in the second month, coupled with a  `LEFT JOIN` looking for `NULL` in one of the joined columns to verify that the first month's event isn't present, you can limit it to the defector users:

This query will return only `'john'`:

```
  SELECT
    event1.user
  FROM
    mytable event1
    -- Join to get the same users in the second month
    INNER JOIN mytable event2 ON event1.user = event2.user
    -- and a LEFT JOIN to find those who attend the month1 event in month2
    LEFT JOIN mytable event_excl 
       ON event2.user = event_excl.user 
       AND event2.month = event_excl.month
       AND event_excl.event = 'event1'
  WHERE
    event1.month = 'october' AND event1.event = 'event1'
    AND event2.month = 'november' AND event2.event = 'event2'
    -- Then include *only* those who don't match the event from the LEFT JOIN
    AND event_excl.event IS NULL
```

If you wrap this query in the subselects to calculate your percentage, it looks like:

```
SELECT (
  SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT event1.user)
  FROM
    mytable event1
    INNER JOIN mytable event2 ON event1.user = event2.user
    LEFT JOIN mytable event_excl 
       ON event2.user = event_excl.user 
       AND event2.month = event_excl.month
       AND event_excl.event = 'event1'
  WHERE
    event1.month = 'october' AND event1.event = 'event1'
    AND event2.month = 'november' AND event2.event = 'event2'
    AND event_excl.event IS NULL
) / (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user)
  FROM mytable
  WHERE month = 'october'
  AND event = 'event1'
) * 100.0 AS defector_percent
```

... And the calculated result is `50%` because `john, sam` were present in both October and November, but `john` defected while `sam` did not.

**Here it is in action:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/460ca/11

**Note about `EXISTS`**: The same thing could be achieved using `EXISTS / NOT EXISTS` as your first posted attempt, but I find the join to be a little easier to map the relationships from. [It is possibly faster as well.](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/). Alternatively, a `NOT IN(SELECT...)` subquery may have similar performance to the `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`.

Comment: event1 is not a table it's a field, so event1.user does not make sense. Or maybe I don't understand is this an alias?

Comment: @alex_b Those are just _table aliases_:  `FROM mytable AS event1 INNER JOIN mytable AS event2`.  They could be changed to anything else if you find it confusing.

Comment: Ah yeah I get it now.

Comment: @alex_b Just used to identify each join side with the event it's bound to in the where clause. They could also have been `mytable as month1 INNER JOIN mytable AS month2`

Comment: This is awesome thanks, trying to understand this all 100% really cool.